# Canada contract law on warranties

Tags: contract-law

Father purchased a car at a dealership and they disclosed that the engine has been repaired. They offered a 3 month free repair warranty on the engine with the purchase of the vehicle. After the purchase they offered to send him the warranty by mail. 2 months later the timing belt ripped and damaged the car. They still have not mailed the warranty to him. Does he have the ability to demand a repair based on the verbal agreement and payment? He also had a witness with him.